# Totally block access to Wp-Admin and Wp-login.php from Non-Admins

Tags: php, authentication, administrator, wp-admin

I want to Block all access to **Wp-admin** and **Wp-login.php** Pages from all members who are not site Admins.

And I don't want to use any plugin for this.

The flow is that, even if people deliberately type “*mydomain.com/wp-admin*” or they deliberately type “*mydomain.com/wp-login.php*” , it should still redirect them to the **Login** or **Register** Pages that I have created-- and they should never see the **Wp- Admin Page** or **Wp-login.php** Page.

I have this Code:

```
    //Redirect WP Login Page
add_filter( 'login_url', 'my_login_page', 10, 3 );
function my_login_page( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ) {
    return home_url( '/my-login-page/?redirect_to=' . $redirect );
}
```

Unfortunately, if you try to access "mydomain.com/wp-admin", it functions well and redirects you to my specified Page.

But if you deliberately type "*mydomain.com/wp-login.php*", it still loads the *wp-login.php* Page.

Please, any PHP Code Snippet that can help me totally block all access to *wp-admin* and **wp-login.php** together?

Regards.